# Are human souls reincarnated in water?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

Are people reincarnated in water? It seems like an odd question but I wonder if it’s a belief found in the Kabbalah.

Comment: Yes. A *mekubal* once mentioned to me that that is why some *mekubalim* (e.g. the Beis Yosef (if I remember correctly)) tried to avoid drinking water because the *neshamos* of *reshaim* are *nisgalgel* in water.

Answer (score 3):

שער הגלגולים הקדמה כב ע"ב

[Here](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaGilgulim.22.16?lang=bi) is a link as well

ויש מי שמתגלגלים במים, והם גם כן נקראים צומח, כנז"ל והם אלו, מי ששופך דמים בעה"ז, מתגלגל במים, וסימניך על הארץ תשפכנו כמים, ונאמר שופך דם האדם באדם דמו ישפך, וענשו הוא שעומד בקלוח המים, ושם המים נקלחים עליו תמיד, והוא רוצה לקום ולעמוד, והמים מפילים אותו בכל רגע, ואין לו מנוחה כלל, ותמיד הוא מתגלגל סביב במקום קלוח המים ההם. גם נרמז זה בפסוק (שמואל ב' י"ד) כי מות נמות וכמים הנגרים ארצה. גם כל מי שמיתתו בחנק, ולא נענש בב"ד של מטה, מתגלגל במים, ושם נחנק בכל רגע כנזכר:

Here is a rough translation: "There are some who reincarnate in water, and they too are called צומח. Those who are get reincarnated in water are those who kill in this world, and the siman is על הארץ תשפכנו כמים, and it also says שופך דם האדם באדם דמו ישפך. His punishment is that he is overtaken in the water; he wants to stand up and rise, but the water takes him down every moment, he never has comfort, and he is always spinning around in the water. This is hinted in the pasuk, כי מות נמות וכמים הנגרים ארצה. Also anyone who is supposed to die by strangulation and is not punished by the earthly court is reincarnated in water, and is strangled every moment, as explained above.

Comment: Thank you! Very interesting